# How do I copy values of one array to another in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I have my code that is reading values from a database and then putting them into an array. I want to copy the values of this array to another array, however when I try, it keeps on throwing an exception,

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*.

I don't seem to see what is wrong. How can I fix this problem?

My code is here:

```
    ' Read values from a database and assign them to an array
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim dataarray As string()

    While reader.Read()
        Dim datatoAdd As string = reader.GetValue(1) & ", " & _
                                  reader.GetValue(2) & ", " & _
                                  reader.GetValue(3) & ", " & _
                                  reader.GetValue(6) & ", " & _
                                  reader.GetValue(7) & ", " & _
                                  reader.GetValue(8) & ", " & _
                                  reader.GetValue(9) & ", " & _
                                  reader.GetValue(10) & ", " & _
                                  reader.GetValue(11)

        dataarray(counter) = datatoAdd
    End While

    reader.Close()
    connection.Close()
    MessageBox.Show('Data added successfully)

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are missing a `counter += 1` inside your While loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement

```
Dim dataarray As string()
```

just *declared* dataarray -- you defined that `dataarray` *can* point to an array of string. Currently, it does not point anywhere. You have to create a *new* array and assign it to `dataarray`.

The easiest way to do so is to specify the size of the array in the declaration:

```
Dim dataarray(UPPER_BOUND) As String
```

This will create an array with indexes 0 to UPPER_BOUND (i.e., with UPPER_BOUND+1 elements). (If you don't know the upper bound yet, don't use an array, but use a `List(Of String)` instead.)

More details:

- MSDN: [Arrays in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

---

**EDIT**: You state in the comments that you don't know the size of the array. In that case you shouldn't be using an array at all. **Arrays are by definition fixed-size data structures.** (Yes, there's `ReDim Preserve`, but it's still not a good idea.)

Instead, use a resizable data structure such as [`List(Of String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). If you really need an array, you can [convert it into an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx) afterwards.

Comment: @Staypa: You replace `Dim dataarray As String()` with `Dim dataarray(5) As String` (if you want your array to have 6 elements -- otherwise, replace 5 with the upper bound you want).

Comment: Its a database so I dont know the size of the array. I cant determine it size

Comment: @Staypa: Then you shouldn't be using an array. Use a resizable data structure such as [List(Of String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead. If you really need an array, you can [convert it into an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx) afterwards.

Comment: @ Heinzi thanks for your help man. I've found a much easier thing to use. An arraylist.

Comment: @Staypa: ArrayList is an old data structure. If you can, use a `List(Of String)` instead. It has the same features as an ArrayList, but it's also type safe.

Comment: @ Heinzi thanks. I'm  just familiar with arraylist but I'll also try working with list(Of string). Just wondering might you be aware of the best way of finding out the largest element in an array still in VB.NET

Comment: @Staypa: `myArray.Max()` should work (at least with .net 3.5, which includes LINQ).

Comment: @ Heinzi looks like myArray.Max() isn't working because its not a member of the arraylist class.

Comment: @Staypa: But you asked for array, not for arraylist. ;-) Use a `List(Of Integer)` (or whatever data type your values are), `Max()` should work there.

Comment: +1 For suggesting `List(Of whatever)`, it's very easy to learn and much better.

Answer (score 0):

VB arrays start at 0 and not 1 don't they? Could that be the problem?

See - http://patorjk.com/programming/tutorials/vbarrays.htm

Comment: It's not the problem in this case. Heinzi has it correct. (BTW I did not downvote)

Comment: I did wonder, should have left this as a comment really as it wasn't a full answer. Hindsight is a wonderful thing. Still, it might be useful to someone who comes along :)

Comment: Usually they start at zero.  You can really botch it up though by treating it as if it starts at 1